# Update a TextView in all Adapters - most efficient way

Tags: android

I have a list of items. Each of them has a set of data displayed with `TextView`s. This data remains mostly unchanged. But I have a **distance** field, which I would like to update whenever I get new lock from location provider.

The question is: **Should I just update my data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my Adapter or is there a more efficient way?**

Seems very expensive to reload all the lists (I have several of them in a ViewPager) just because one TextView in each list item needs to be updated.

Here is my `getView()` from my adapter. It might help:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.eventrow, parent, false);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventTitle);
        holder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDistance);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(((EventItem) getItem(position)).getTitle());
    holder.distance.setText(String.valueOf(((EventItem) getItem(position)).getDistance()));

    return convertView;
}
```

**I also thought about directly referencing the `holder.distance` but it seems like a bad idea to do it outside `getView()`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to modify your data is to change your list item and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The only alternative that comes to my mind is to set again the adapter on the list view which is way more expensive. There are no other ways.

So the answer is: you HAVE to go through `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I'll wait a day, maybe someone can add something, but if it's the way to go, so be it (and then you'll get an accept of course).

Comment: No probleam @MichałK, hope it helped anyway. Let me know if you come out with something. Thanks

Comment: Well it certainly works, maybe if there's more lightweight option I'll change it later, but for now I can't think of a better solution too.